# Can an aquired domain with a different TDL get you to a specfic section of your main site?

Tags: website-design, website-features, visual-website-optimizer

Is it possible to have a domain, with several other top level domain (TLD) extensions and use those other extensions to get to different parts of your site?

For example:
example.com is the main page.
example.menu gets you to the same site, but to the menu page.

I understand that they're different domains, but if you owned the TLD extensions is it possible to use them in this way?

Comment: Does your hosting have a management area like cpanel?

Comment: I'm not online yet mate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That that is possible.

So, example.com will be the main website. And let's say you created a menu page like example.com/menu

Now, if you get another domain like example.menu then you can easily redirect this to example.com/menu

Comment: What about if I owned example.com and example.pizza. instead of a example.pizza search redirecting to example.com/pizza, can it just view as example.pizza but is the same page as the main domain: example.com/pizza?  I don't own the .com TLD so if I have a extension which does not cover all the facets of my site, i t won't make sense to have /pizza when people are going to example.photography and they see example.pizza/photography etc

Comment: To answer the first part of your question yes it is possible but you will have duplicate content issue. Your second part of the question is not very clear. Just to help you understand more, if there is a page that shouldn't be viewed from 2 different domain, instead secondary URL should redirect to Primary URL. There are some exceptions but it needs to be planned well.

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling to explain. From what you've said it doesn't seem possible unless I duplicate the sites and then redirect. I was hoping for a user to search one of my shorter extensions like example.coffee and only see those words in The browser instead of seeing example.com/coffee. This is so I can break up the site for different content. But I hear you can just put it in front of the domain like coffee.example.com and if I own the extension example.coffee it would redirect this site there. Its longer and uglier but I guess I'll have to deal.